# How to extract data with dd-mm-yyyy format from string column in azure data flow?

Tags: regex, azure, regex-group, azure-data-factory

I have a dataset that contains dates and string together. I want to extract the date then save it in a `date` column and string in the `task` column. I am using azure data flow to achieve this data transformation.

```
regexExtract({Finish Date Activity}, '^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\-)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\-)\d{4}$', 1)
```

[image]

But this does not seem to work for me and getting `Unable to parse the expression. Please make sure it is valid.` error. Can anyone help me to solve this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
((?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)
```

Or, if your dates are always at the start of the text:

```
^((?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mG2y5N/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start of a capturing group #1 (you extract this group value with `1` argument)
- `(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` - a non-capturing group: day value
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])` - month part
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d{2}(?:\d{2})?` - two- or four-digit year.